# Pandas: Conditional groupby and max

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe-

`my_df`-

```
user_id |  spend |  transaction_id |
--------+--------+-----------------|
1       |   45   |        12       |
2       |   33   |        45       |
3       |   12   |        33       |
1       |   22   |        56       |
1       |   77   |        99       |
```

In order to de-duplicate the above table, my goal was to get the greatest `transaction_id` given a `user_id`. So I did the following-

```
deduped_df = my_df.groupby("user_id")[["transaction_id"]].max().reset_index()
```

which gave me the following result -

```
user_id |  transaction_id |
--------+-----------------|
1       |   99            |
2       |   45            |
3       |   33            |
```

Now, what if I want to apply the above operation to just the **first 100** `user_id` and discard the other rows? Also, I lost my `spend` column. How do I retain that column in the above operation?

I want my final result to look like this -

```
user_id |  spend |  transaction_id |
--------+--------+-----------------|
1       |   77   |        99       |
2       |   33   |        45       |
3       |   12   |        33       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter first 100 rows `user_id` - values are sorted, because `groupby` sorting by default:

```
deduped_df = my_df.groupby("user_id")[["transaction_id"]].max().head(100).reset_index()
```

If need sorting manually:

```
my_df = my_df.sort_values('user_id')
deduped_df = (my_df.groupby("user_id", sort=False)[["transaction_id"]]
                   .max()
                   .head(100)
                   .reset_index())
```

---

If need first 100 `user_id` without sorting add parameter `sort=False` to `groupby`:

```
deduped_df = (my_df.groupby("user_id", sort=False)[["transaction_id"]]
                   .max()
                   .head(100)
                   .reset_index())
```

> Also, I lost my spend column. How do I retain that column in the above operation?

It is expected, because this column is not used in `groupby` and also is not used any aggregate function for it, so lost.

So possible solution is add some aggregate function, like `sum` for `spend` column:

```
deduped_df = (my_df.groupby("user_id", sort=False)
                   .agg({"transaction_id":'max', 'spend':'sum'})
                   .head(100)
                   .reset_index())
```

EDIT: If need rows with first 100 maximum use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices and select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
deduped_df = my_df.loc[my_df.groupby("user_id")["transaction_id"].idxmax().head(100)]
```

Comment: @kev - yes, or omit it, because `sort=True` is default value, so `my_df.groupby("user_id", sort=True)` working same like `my_df.groupby("user_id")`

Comment: oh did not know that `groupby()` in pandas automatically sorts the columns, is that a fact?

Comment: great, thanks! Also, there is no other way to include the other columns after `groupby()`?

Comment: @kev - I think yes, it depends what need. Can you explain more?

Comment: for example, if i did not want to aggregate the `spend` column, but still want to include it in my dataframe after `groupby()` operation, there is no other way?

Comment: @kev - If you think no aggregation it means first value per `user_id` ? What means no aggreagation? Or converting values to `list` ? Because aggregate means reduce number of rows by unique `user_id` - so all columns have to be reduced some way - e.g. by `max`, by `sum` or if need first values then aggregate by `first`.